# Finding closest x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have coordinates (x, y) of place where I am currently and array of objects with coordinates of destinations.

Coordinates x and y are just representing of fields in map like this:

[image]

and it is up to 100x100.

`myPosition` is array: `[ 13, 11 ]` where 13 is x and 11 is y (demonstratively marked it as red in above jpg).

`destinations` is array of object:

```
[ { x: 22, y: 13 },
{ x: 16, y: 25 },
{ x: 20, y: 11 },
{ x: 76, y: 49 },
{ x: 65, y: 47 },
{ x: 82, y: 33 },
{ x: 86, y: 35 },
{ x: 61, y: 59 },
{ x: 62, y: 52 },
{ x: 18, y: 52 },
{ x: 24, y: 49 },
{ x: 52, y: 55 },
{ x: 20, y: 57 },
{ x: 80, y: 11 },
{ x: 55, y: 61 },
{ x: 46, y: 59 },
{ x: 77, y: 19 },
{ x: 2, y: 22 },
{ x: 78, y: 23 },
{ x: 86, y: 51 },
{ x: 75, y: 46 },
{ x: 6, y: 8 },
{ x: 25, y: 12 },
{ x: 81, y: 21 },
{ x: 53, y: 58 } ]
```

I need some tips or algorithm which will sort destination array of object in order from closest to my position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you got is called the nearest neighbor problem.

Two solutions, depening on where you need to take your problem:

1. You could simply do a brute force distance search with the usual optimization of skipping the square-root:

Some code:

```
function DistSquared(pt1, pt2) {
    var diffX = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    var diffY = pt1.y - pt2.y;
    return (diffX*diffX+diffY*diffY);
}

 closest = destinations[0];
 shortestDistance = DistSquared(myPosition, destinations[0]);
 for (i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
     var d = DistSquared(myPosition, destinations[i]);
     if (d < shortestDistance) {
         closest = destinations[i];
         shortestDistance = d;
     }
 }
```

2. If you are going to make repeated nearest neighbor queries on the same  `destinations` array, you can use an algorithm known as a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).  This where you build a binary tree representation of your grid of points by partitioning it in half many times along a different axis.

Comment: Well but if I have `let myPosition = [0,0]; let destinations = [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 0}];` then `0.1` and `1.0` is closer than `1.1` but the snippet code showing closest `1.1` as I tested here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXRPXZ?editors=0010 Basically this codepen doesn't work at all :(

Comment: @BT101 - I fixed it.  I think I had a typo or a misunderstanding about javascript for-each.

Comment: I had an inconsistent misspelling for "destnations" vs "destinations".  :)

Comment: Could you please provide new codepen link? I'm still geting invalid output https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXRPXZ?editors=0010

Comment: In your IDE example, you literally forgot to define `myPositions`.  Add this line to the top of your file: `myPosition={x:0,y:0};`